# Custom Collection View Cell adding images

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a property in the customCell.h file which is a UIImageView, i have synthesized it in the .m and added it to the contentView in the initWithFrame -

```
self.contentView addSubView:myImageView;
```

in the cellForRow method I call

```
customCell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageName:@"someImageName.jpg"] like normal
```

The image does not get added because i'm guessing initWithFrame gets called before the image is assigned to to image view

any solutions?

Comment: How is customCell being set in cellForRow? I would be unusual for it to be with initWithFrame.

Comment: BoardCollectionViewCell *customCell = (BoardCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView2 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BoardCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: To extend @farski question: where are the rest of the custom cell's subviews defined?  You can setup the image view with the rest of the subviews.

Comment: Dequeueing a cell isn't guaranteed to init a new cell; that's the whole point. It will reuse an existing cell instance if there's one. Even when it does need to init a cell, it uses `initWithStyle`, so you'd have to do your setup in there.

Comment: Sorry, read that too fast and forgot you were using a collection view and not a table view.

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code; the whole cellForItem (you had said cellForRow, hopefully that was a typo), where you register the cell identifier, etc.

Comment: As @farski says, you should provide some code that shows us how you are treating the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source Example - http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

You can design your own custom cell using a nib(.xib) file in Interface Builder.

After that make outlets as the property to that custom cell.

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use the following patch.

```
CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customTableCellId];

if(cell == nil) {
   NSArray *nib = [[ NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

   cell = [ nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.myImageView.image = [ UIImage imageNamed: [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
.....
.....
```